# (PY4E: Exercise. 9.1) Can anyone please explain how (and why) Line 12 in this code works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I have been working on the **Python for Everybody Chapter 9 Exercise 1**.

The exercise assignment is as follows:

**Exercise 1:** Download a copy of the file [www.py4e.com/code3/words.txt](http://www.py4e.com/code3/words.txt)

Write a program that reads the words in words.txt and stores them as keys in a dictionary. It doesn’t matter what the values are. Then you can use the in operator as a fast way to check whether a string is in the dictionary.

And here is link to a screenshot of my code:

[Ex 9.1 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VErpk.png)

Basically, I would like an explanation of what **Lines 10-12** is actually doing in this code, especially Line 12. (I became stuck/confused with the exercise and took lines 10-12 from another person's example)

I know that the code succeeds in storing all of the words from the file into a dictionary as the exercise asked, but I just don't understand **how** it did so?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Lines 10-12 repeatedly do `make_dictionary[myword]=someirrelevantvalue`. When the loop completes, the keys of `make_dictionary` will contain one copy of every word in the file, because a `dict` can't have duplicate keys. This is a trick that languages like Awk and Python < 2.5 used to use to emulate sets. Except, of course, that the programmers who did it, myself included, didn't call it a trick. We called it a *pattern*.  Idiomatic Python from 2.5  onwards (2006) would do `make_dictionary = set()` in line 5 and `make_dictionary.add(word)` in line 12, and leave `count` out entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 10 loops over all of the words in the list `words`. The code in lines 11 and 12 is executed for every element in that list, each time keeping the current element in the variable `word`.

Line 11 just increments a counter (`count`) by 1 every loop, I assume just to have something to put as the values in the dictionary.

Line 12 adds the current value of `count` to the dictionary `make_dictionary` at key `word`.

The result is a dictionary where the keys are the words from the file, and the values integers starting from 1.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it was very clear and helped me understand!

Comment: @ChristineM If the answer worked for you, please accept it.